# docker compose - ignore build context path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, suppress

I have docker-compose.yml file with `build context` property specified like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: my-service
    build:
      context: foo
    ports:
    - 8088:8088

  # other services
```

When I run `docker-compose up` locally, build context **does** exist and everything works fine. However, my CI server is configured to use the same docker-compose.yml file but there is **no** build context (images are copied as .tar archive via SSH and then loaded via docker load). 
Now I've got an error:

> ERROR: build path /foo either does not exist, is not accessible, or is
>   not a valid URL.

So I've tried to find a way to suppress looking for this build context when running `docker-compose up` (I don't want to build images cause they are  already up-to-date), but `docker-compose up --no-build` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: just give set it to an empty dir if you want to avoid setting it to  `.`. But the directory must exists thats why (amongst other reasons) a common practice to create a `docker` dir in the project root, and move the `Docerfile` into it. Then build in the `docker` directory which will be an empty context.

Comment: But the point is that I don't want to modify docker-compose.yml file. This file is copied from repository to CI server, so I don't want to change it (I would have to use some regex probably). Alternatively, I can maintain two separate compose files, but I'd like to avoid it if it's unnecessary

Comment: Did you try to add a `foo` directory in your root of a repo with am empty `.keep` or `Readme` file in it which explains why the empty dir is necessary.

Comment: On CI server there is no foo directory. There is just .tar archive with docker image

Comment: I opened a feature request based on your question, in case anyone wants to thumbs-up there: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7674

Comment: I found an open discussion on the same issue https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4047. it does not solve the problem but there are some workarounds

Answer (score 3):

docker-compose.override.yml is good solution in this case. You may override only build block and this is not hard to mantain as two independent files.

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    my-service:
      build:
        context: foo
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
  services:
    my-service:
      container_name: my-service
      image: my-service
      ports:
        - 8088:8088
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Comment: IMHO, it leads to an extra complexity. Just use `docker-compose up --no-build`.  As of what @zeehio has said.

Comment: @EmranBatmanGhelich we can use --no-build for up, but we still face the same issue for down. docker-compose down still needs build context and --no-build doesn't work for down

Answer (score 3):

I posted your issue as a feature request on the  docker-compose repository. Let's see how it progresses:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7674

Meanwhile, you will have to workaround this by modifying your CI script that does the `docker-compose up --no-build` so it does the `mkdir -p ...` that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution, until "docker-compose config" provides a way to skip the directory-exists check, is to automatically create those directories that "docker-compose config" expects.

Here is a one-liner that does this:

```
egrep '    (context:|build)' < docker-compose.yml | sed -E 's/\s+\S+:\s*//' | xargs mkdir -p .
```

It's ugly, but I couldn't figure out another way. (The .extends. way mentioned by dngnezdi is not a solution, as I needed an automatic method.)

Comment: I tried it but I get an error "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile": Dockerfile and if I create an empty Dockerfile I get an error that "the Dockerfile (Dockerfile) cannot be empty". what did you do with that?